# Is "hiree" a word or are there alternative words with such meaning?

Tags: meaning

I need a word that means "someone that was hired."

For example a trainee is someone who is being trained.
I google'd hiree and I got some results, but am not sure if this is a proper word.

Comment: I'm not sure how "official" it is, but it's certainly commonly used in business in the US.  And at least [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hiree) recognizes it.

Comment: *newhire* is a common term in the US for someone newly hired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, the word is *hireling*, but that word is almost always used pejoratively, hinting either the work is menial or the worker is only fit for menial work.

The *-ee* ending usually refers to someone who is currently having something done to him (or occasionally, currently doing something fairly passive, like an *attendee*).  A hiring is the act of bringing someone into a company, and can be considered a momentary act, or act of a few hours at most.

Have you considered just *employee*?  Or *new hire*, if that is appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question after reading a CNN article:

> Potential hires can wear a VR headset and "within a matter of seconds can experience a job in a very real-life atmosphere," according to Kerstin Wagner, Deutsche Bahn's head of talent acquisition.
>   [CNN article](https://edition.cnn.com/2019/02/26/tech/vr-transforming-hr-intl-biz-evolved/index.html)

Seeing the word "hires" used in this way was jarring, to me at least. My research on this shows that American dictionaries tend to list "hire" as a person who is hired. These are *American Heritage Dictionary*, *Random House dictionaries (Unabridged and Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary)*, *Merriam-Webster* and *Longman Business Dictionary*.

All BrE dictionaries I checked that list "hire" as a noun to mean a person hired marked it as "American" or "North American". Furthermore many entries mark this as informal.

I thought the accepted word for this was "hiree", but it's not universally listed in dictionaries. We find it in *American Heritage*, *Random House* publications and *Collins*, both AmE and BrE dictionaries. However it is missing from *Cambridge*, *Macmillan*, *Longman*, *Merriam-Webster*, and *Oxford Living Dictionaries*. And for what it's worth this spell checker doesn't recognize it. Neither does *Microsoft Word* nor *LibreOffice* word processor. *Wiktionary* recognizes it.

As I said, I thought the word "hiree" was universally accepted, but I'd now be hesitant to use it.

Comment: In BrE, I would say referring to a person as "a hire" in this context would be acceptable. Most people would also understand "hirees" in context - but the -ee suffix doesn't seem to sit easily, similarly with the counterpart word "firee", the words seem to have an air of comedy about them. I'm not quite clear why, because words like "payee" are legitimate.